# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This has given me issues since i installed AS it has been having different issues and this is the latest that comes on when I try to build gradle, i have cleaned, updated SDK , restarted but till now no solution, please help.

Comment: Please provide your `build.gradle` file as well as the console output

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue before , so i try `Clean project` then `Rebuild project` after that i try `invalidate caches & Restart` and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by removing

```
maven {
     url "https://maven.google.com"
}
```

in the `allprojects { repositeries{ ... } }` lines below the `buildscript { ... }` lines.

Then, I add `google()` before `jcenter()` like that :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    } 
    ...
}
```